# Nested Form with Many-to-Many relationship - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, nested-forms

I'm learning Rails and I'am pretty stuck building a nested form with many to many relationship.

I was able to get the many-to-many relationship working with has_many :through, but when it comes down to create the views and the controllers to get it working I'm getting stuck.

See models relationships below:

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :timesheet_payments
    has_many :employees, :through => :timesheet_payments

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :timesheet_payments,
            :reject_if => :all_blank,
            :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees   
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :timesheet_payments
    has_many :timesheets, :through => :timesheet_payments   
end

class TimesheetPayment < ActiveRecord::Base   
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :timesheet
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee,
                                  :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

See db schema below:

```
  create_table "timesheet_payments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "employee_id"
    t.integer  "timesheet_id"
    t.float    "basic_hours"
    t.float    "sunday_bh_hours"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "timesheets", force: true do |t|
    t.date     "upload_date"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "employees", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "pps_no"
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.date     "dob"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "ph_number"
    t.float    "basic_rop"
    t.float    "sunday_bh_rop"
    t.string   "email"
    t.date     "date_joined"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end
```

I want to create a form where I can create a new Timesheet, display all Employees and an field to add the basic_hours and sunday_bh_hours for each employee.

This would be similar to the idea of a relationship between Customer -> Order -> Products.

I hope this makes sense! Thanks in advance!

I tried this view form

```
<%= form_for(@payment, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <% if @payment.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@payment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this payment from being saved:</h2>
    <% end %>

    <!--creates a new timesheet -->
    <%= f.fields_for :timesheet do |builder| %> 
          <%= builder.label "New timesheet" %>
          <%= builder.text_field :upload_date %>
          <p></p>
    <% end %>

    <!-- Add worked hours for each employee -->
    <% @employee.each do |t| %>
          <%= f.label t.fname  %>
          <br />
          <%= f.label "Basic Hours" %>
          <%= f.text_field :basic_hours  %>
          <%= f.label "Sunday/BH Hours" %>
          <%= f.text_field :sunday_bh_hours  %>
          <br />
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

It is loading fine but i really can't get my head around how I go about creating the "create" method on the controller.

I have the "new" method is following:

```
def new 
        @payment = TimesheetPayment.new
        @timesheet = Timesheet.new
        @employee = Employee.all
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the view (form) code you tried and the errors or conflicts?

Comment: I edited the post to include the form as requested... just can't get my head around the create method.

Comment: still stuck on this... tried different approaches but can't get my head around the create method